# Phonegap Plugins: Utilizando câmera com lanterna ligada

Tags: apache-cordova, plugin

Necessito saber se é possível ou se existe algum plugin que permita que eu abra a câmera com o flash(ou lanterna) ligado(a). Necessito disso para um projeto, para verificar o local do estouro do flash. Já tentei diversas formas, utilizando o próprio plugin de câmera do `cordova` juntamente com o plugin de Flash(EddyVerbruggen), porém da erro na câmera ao ligar o flash. Alguma solução?

Imagem do erro ao acessar a câmera com o flash ligado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo. Não é por causa que está tentando ligar o *flash* em um dispositivo sem esse recurso? Ajudaria se [edit] a pergunta e incluir o erro mostrado.

Comment: Obrigado re22, já editei.Não, estou tentando ligar no meu dispositivo, que possui flash(lanterna).

Comment: experimenta o app flash da camera livre

Answer (score 1):

Olha, sua pergunta ficou muito genérica, não é possível descobrir com certeza o que é o erro 3.
Provavelmente se você olhar o log no **adb** deve existir mais informações sobre o erro, de qualquer forma fiz uma leitura rápida do código do plugin utilizado (**EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin**) e percebi que o plugin utiliza a câmera para corrigir um problema com Nexus 5 (além de utilizar em uma função para dar toggle no flash).

O problema é que ele só da um release da câmera depois de receber uma action para desligar o flash. Acredito que por isso é possível ver a **Toast** de câmera não encontrada.

De qualquer forma fazer modificações no(s) plugins é bem complicado, ainda mais se está utilizando Cordova para evitar o Java, neste caso a melhor solução é utilizar um plugin que atenda melhor sua necessidade. Por sorte com uma busca de 5minutos no Google encontrei o plugin abaixo que permite tirar fotos e ativar o flash sem problemas. Agora você tem a liberdade de utilizar todos os plugins e alternar entre eles para as mais diferentes ações.

https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin

Comment: Olá Pedro Henrique, verifiquei esse plugin Canvas, realmente tem a opção de ligar e desligar flash e tirar foto, porém, o mesmo não funciona, deve haver algum erro com esse plugin, pois ao adicioná-lo, o meu projeto não roda mais.

Comment: @EvertonMartins Você consegue enviar um log do adb?

Comment: Depois de um século, verifiquei este plugin e tem as opções AUTO/ON/OFF, que acho que não é o que eu queria, pois queria algo que deixasse o flash contínuo, antes mesmo de focar ou tirar a foto.